# Ext JS ext_scaffold generator rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

I am trying to use `ext_scaffold` plugin for rails3 app. I've downloaded the Ext Javascript framework from [here](http://www.extjs.com/products/extjs/download.php) and unzip it into my rails appn/public/ext.

I have installed ext_scaffold plugin from [here](http://git://github.com/martinrehfeld/ext_scaffold.git).

Now when I try to generate scaffold using :

```
rails generate ext_scaffold post title:string
```

I get an error "Could not find generator ext_scaffold".

I have referred [this site](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/ext_scaffold_generator).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

On the [github](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/ext_scaffold) there is a note at the top it said: This project has not been adapted to Rails3, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

there is a new project up on [here](https://github.com/mojomaze/extjs_scaffold):  which seems to be the "new" extjs_scaffold.

give it a try - it's pretty cool! - hopes this helps

Comment: thnx mario..will try that & get back :)